# AutoMapper - Inheritance preserve reference

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have the following scenario

Entity framework classes classes:

```
public class Block
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BlockLocation> BlockLocations { get; set; }
    public BlockType Type { get; set; }
}

public class BlockLocation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid BlockId { get; set; }
    public Block Block { get; set; }
}
```

And my Domain Entities look like

```
public class Block
{
    public Block(BlockType type = BlockType.None) : this()
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    private Block() { }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<BlockLocation> BlockLocations { get; set; }
    public BlockType Type { get; set; }
}

public class LiveBlock : Block
{
    public LiveBlock() : base(BlockType.Live) { }
}

public class UnsequencedBlock : Block
{
    public UnsequencedBlock() : base(BlockType.Unsequenced) { }
}

public class BlockLocation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid BlockId { get; set; }
    public Block Block { get; set; }
}

public enum BlockType
{
    None = 0,
    Live,
    Unsequenced
}
```

And what I want to do is map from Entity Framework to a Domain entity to the child type and also preserve the reference so that I don't get a stack overflow

My mappings are

```
cfg.CreateMap<Data.Block, Domain.LiveBlock>();
cfg.CreateMap<Data.Block, Domain.UnsequencedBlock>();
cfg.CreateMap<Data.Block, Domain.Block>().PreserveReferences().ConstructUsing((block, context) =>
        {
            if (block.Type == BlockType.Live)
            {
                // This loops until stack overflow
                return context.Mapper.Map<Domain.LiveBlock>(block);
            }

            if (block.Type == BlockType.Unsequenced)
            {
                return context.Mapper.Map<Domain.LiveBlock>(block);
            }

            return context.Mapper.Map<Domain.Block>(block);
        });

 cfg.CreateMap<Data.BlockLocation, Domain.BlockLocation>();
```

And I'm trying to do the following:

```
// This is the EF entity
var block = new Data.Block
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Type = BlockType.Live,
    BlockLocations = new List<Data.BlockLocation>
    {
        new BlockLocation {Id = Guid.NewGuid()},
        new BlockLocation {Id = Guid.NewGuid()}
    }
};

block.BlockLocations[0].Block = block;
block.BlockLocations[1].Block = block;

// Trying to create a Domain entity
var domainBlock = Mapper.Map<Data.Block, Domain.Block>(block);
```

The result that I want to achieve is for **domainBlock** to be of type LiveBlock and have a list of BlockLocations which in turn have the same LiveBlock entity as their **Block** property

What I get is a loop in ConstructUsing, until I get stack overflow.

Now, my questions are:

- Can this be achieved with AutoMapper?
- If yes, can it be done with ContructUsing? I've also tried ConvertUsing, but I get the same result.
- Some other approach maybe?

I know that a way of doing to would be to Ignore the **BlockLocations** property from **Domain.Block** and map them separately, but I would like to have Automapper to that automatically.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try setting PreserveReferences on all the maps involved. But do check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Because once you're calling Map in your mapping code, you're kind of taking over things.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried settings PreserveReferences every where, but it still doesn't work. I'll have a look at the execution plan now.

Comment: Tried looking at the expression, can't see anything standing out. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: :) What I'm pretty sure that plan tells you is that you're breaking the chain of PreserveReferences checks by calling Map manually. So a possible fix is to check that yourself. But the end result cannot be pretty. The root cause here is that you're trying to decide the map to use dynamically. But AM chooses the type map based on the source and destination types.

Comment: And another thing. The cache is keyed by source object and destination type, so the fact that you mapped block first to some other type won't help when you call Map manually for another type. I'm guessing the recursion could still stop somewhere, but you have to help AM with it.

Comment: Try passing the context in your Map call. That way you'll share the cache between calls.

Comment: How do I do that exactly :) ?

Comment: One of the Map overloads takes a context as a parameter, you just have to pass the context you receive. That happens by default when AM does the mapping for child objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with Lucian's help

I changed the mapper to the following

```
cfg.CreateMap<Data.Block, Domain.LiveBlock>().PreserveReferences();
cfg.CreateMap<Data.Block, Domain.UnsequencedBlock>().PreserveReferences();
cfg.CreateMap<Data.Block, Domain.Block>().PreserveReferences().ConstructUsing((block, context) =>
    {
        if (block.Type == BlockType.Live)
        {
            var b = new LiveBlock();
            return context.Mapper.Map(block, b, context);
        }

        if (block.Type == BlockType.Unsequenced)
        {
            var unsequencedBlock = new UnsequencedBlock();
            return context.Mapper.Map(block, unsequencedBlock, context);
        }

        return context.Mapper.Map<Domain.Block>(block);
    });

cfg.CreateMap<Data.BlockLocation, Domain.BlockLocation>().PreserveReferences();
```

The secred was usint the Map method that takes the context as a parameter

```
context.Mapper.Map(block, unsequencedBlock, context);
```